# Open a internet web site from a custom static tab in teams app

Tags: teams-toolkit

I'm trying to open a web page that's available on the internet without authentication from a custom Teams app tab. The page can be openend in an iframe also.

Using fiddler I can see the page being accessed, but Teams doesn't display the tab.

Should this be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is definitely possible. The easiest way to do this is generate a app installer using App studio app in teams:
[image of app studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50BF6.png)